# Can I convert from this Json to list in c#?

Tags: c#, json, list, json.net

I want to convert this Json to list in c#.

Here's my JSON string and class

```
{"Headers":[{"KeyValue":"Hello AA"},{"KeyValue":"Hello BB"}],"Footers":[{"KeyValue":"Wifi Password : 11112222"}]}
```

```
public class Template
    {
        public List<HeaderInfo> Headers { get; set; }

        public List<FooterInfo> Footers { get; set; }
    }
    public class HeaderInfo
    {
        public string KeyValue { get;set; }
    }
    public class FooterInfo
    {
        public string KeyValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Deserialize:

```
lstData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Template>>(templateData.ToString());
```

When I try convert it , it shows this problem:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. `{"name":"value"}`) into type `System.Collections.Generic.List<DXClass.Model.Template>` because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. `[1,2,3]`) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'Headers', line 1, position 11.'

Comment: Looks like your Json Convert, Parse or JsonSerialize call is wrong but you didn't include that so we have no clue.

Comment: Here's my conversion
lstData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Template>>(templateData.ToString());

Comment: you should [edit] the question. Your top level object is not a list, so doing  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Template>(data);` should fix that specific error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing it incorrectly, your equivalent of JSON is  `Template`  object, not the `List<Template>`. It should be like this `Template template = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Template>(inoutJson);`

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON string is not a list but a single object. When you'd call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Template>` the deserialization will succeed.

If you expect it to be a list, the JSON would look like this:

`[{"Headers":[{"KeyValue":"Hello AA"},{"KeyValue":"Hello BB"}],"Footers":[{"KeyValue":"Wifi Password : 11112222"}]}]`

Comment: For final output , I just want to get each KeyValue of Header and footer.

Comment: Using the snippet from my post (`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Template>`) you can access the KeyValues like this:

```
var template = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Template>(json);
var headers = result.Headers;
var footers = result.Footers;
```
If you want them in one list you can do this:

```
        var template = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Template>(json)!;
        var allKeyValues = template.Headers.Select(h => h.KeyValue)
            .Concat(template.Footers.Select(f => f.KeyValue));
```